# what is difference between Bounce and BootUp the server?

Tags: java, server, middleware, application-server, bounce

While looking into the Server environment I found the different terminologies some of them I am aware of like `shutdown`, `restart` and `start`

I don't know what does actually `Bounce` and `BootUp` services do? according to me bounce means `restart` and `bootup` simply start server.

Anybody can explain briefly what does actually `Bounce` and `BootUp` do?

Comment: what application server do you use? apache, nginx, java servlets...

Comment: it can be any server I want to know terminology of Bounce and Bootup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after browsing some article on google, i got to know the term `Bounce server` means `shutdown` the `server` first and then `boot up`

`boot up` is process to bring up the `server`